# Duda con uso de funcion strtok

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Quisiera pedir ayuda con el uso de la función `strtok`, tengo este pedazo de código pero no logro almacenar los valores que busco:

```
int count = 0;
  while(fgets(aux,999,f)){   

    f1 = atoi(strtok(aux,"[]\t"));
    f2 = atoi(strtok(NULL,"[]\t"));
    f3 = atoi(strtok(NULL,"[]\t"));

    node[count].id = f1;
    node[count].links=f2;
    node[count].f3=f3;

    count++;
}
```

- ¿Está mal implementado el código?
- ¿Tendre mal puestos los delimitadores?
  La idea es buscar para cada nodo (source) la cantidad de links que tienen, osea, para el nodo 0 debo buscar cuando el hops es = 1, y luego imprimir: Nodo :0 links : 3 Para realizar el conteo de los links tengo un for asi: for(i=0;i

**Adjunto imagen del archivo que debo leer**:

[image: archivo a leer]

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no tengo ni idea, porque **no dices que valores buscas**, ni tampoco **lo que estás consiguiendo**. Si adivinar fuera mi fuerte, me habría tocado la lotería y no estará aquí :-)

Comment: La idea es buscar para cada nodo (source) la cantidad de links que tienen, osea, para el nodo 0 debo buscar cuando el hops es = 1, y luego imprimir: Nodo :0 links : 3       Para realizar el conteo de los links tengo un for asi:    for(i=0;i<number_of_nodes;i++){
  
    (f1==0 && f3==1){
      q[0]=q[0]+1;
      nodes[0].links=q[0];
    
}     pero la verdad es que no me esta resultando

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir la información que falta. Si esperas que la gente se tenga que leer los comentarios para entender la pregunta perderás muchas respuestas

Comment: Dices `para el nodo 0 debo buscar cuando el hops es = 1, y luego imprimir: Nodo :0 links : 3`. Pero me estoy dejando los *ojitos* mirando ese gráfico (en lugar de pegar texto, que es mucho mas fácil y práctico) y son **incapaz** de ver de donde sacas ese `links: 3`.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` es una función que busca cualquiera de los separadores indicados y lo reemplaza por un caracter nulo. Posteriormente devuelve un puntero al inicio de la cadena.

Es decir, esta instrucción:

```
f1 = atoi(strtok(aux,"[]\t"));
```

No va a localizar lo que esté entre los corchetes, sino que devolverá una cadena vacía, ya que el primer caracter a evaluar es justamente uno de los delimitadores.

Para extraer los números de, por ejemplo esta secuencia:

```
[0]\t[1]\t2\t
```

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
strtok(aux, "[");                 // descartamos el corchete inicial
char * v1 = strtok(NULL, "]");    // Recuperamos el 0
strtok(NULL, "[");                // descartamos todo hasta el siguiente corchete
char * v2 = strtok(NULL, "]");    // Recuperamos el 1
strtok(NULL, "\t");               // descartamos el tabulador (ojo, solo 1 tabulador)
char * v3 = strtok(NULL, "\t");   // Recuperamos el 2
```